# Key_load_public : How does this particular 'no such file or directory' map to aws endpoint connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services

[Simple ssh key-load-public serverfault article](https://serverfault.com/questions/822954/permission-denied-publickey-with-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory)

UPDATE 1:'aws ec2 describe-instances' works just fine and gives valid data.

UPDATE 2 : aws Cloudtrail opentunnel reports 'dialfailure'     ??

Hello!
How does the 'key_load_public: no such file or directory'
from 'aws --debug ec2-instance-connect ssh --eice-options endpointId=eice-0245522166cfxxxx --instance-id i-0760bc8f6f29nnnn --connection-type eice --instance-ip 172.16.123.xx' mean?
The above link is for a simple ssh OUTSIDE aws.
The instance has 2 private interfaces. I have seen a server fault response that NAT is required for endpoints to connect to cloudshell....true?

Thx.